# php echoing user results same page error with action tag not allowing php inside of it

Tags: php, html, forms

-------------------UPDATE SOLVED
the file was a .html extension and not a .php file  -  -  Thanks for the help!

I've seen a few posts explaining how to echo html submitted form information on the same page using php.  When I try to implement this I always get an error when playing php tags inside the form action = "".

Here is the code...

```
Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: when the script runs 'name' is not found int post variable so change the code as `<?php echo (!empty($_POST["name"])) ? $_POST["name"] : ""; ?>` otherwise everything is fine.

Comment: what is your page name where you are using this code ? is it .php or .html ?

Comment: Oh I see -  my index has to be a .php file now just to use a little php.  Thought I could just add it in like a script.  It works after changing index.html to index.php

Answer (score 0):

Just a try:

```
Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
<form action=<?php echo '"' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"'; ?> method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: No need of  concatenation of string. As the variable is being parsed in "(double quotes)

Comment: this results in hello method="post"> because something isn't closing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo isset($_POST["name"])?"Hello, " . $_POST["name"]:""; ?><br>

<form action=<?php echo '"' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"'; ?> method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```